# Get product remain quantity in Magento CE 1.7?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I want to get the remain quantity of a given product. I'm going to create a report in admin panel which highlights the remaining quantity and re-order level quantity against each product. I was able to get the re-order level quantity by inventory details. And I want to get remain quantity for a given product. Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
<?php 
$num= Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); 
echo "Remaining products: ".$num;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this. But this returns the entire quantity for the given product. Not the remaining quantity after completing orders.

Comment: go to `system>config>inventory` tab and check out `Decrease Stock When Order is Placed` is `yes` or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the remaining quantity for products in the cart, you need to take into account configurable vs simple products:

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
   $cart_product = $item->getProduct();

   if ($option = $item->getOptionByCode('simple_product')) {
      $cart_simple_product = $option->getProduct();
   } else {
      $cart_simple_product = $this->getProduct();
   }

   $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($cart_simple_product);
   $max_available_quantity = (int)$stock->getQty();
}
?>
```